# Add TraceListener for WCF in code

Tags: c#, wcf, system.diagnostics, tracelistener

Given the following `app.config` configuration for trace listeners,

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="traceListener" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\log.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

How can I achieve the same using code rather than XML?

I tried the following (after deleting the aforementioned section in the `app.config` file):

```cs
var source = new TraceSource(
    "System.ServiceModel",
    SourceLevels.Information | SourceLevels.ActivityTracing );
source.Listeners.Add( new XmlWriterTraceListener( @"C:\log.svclog" ) );
```

If I write directly to `source` it appears in the listener; however, it does not capture any of the WCF trace messages.

Comment: I think you have to use reflection to get access to the static list of TraceSources and then add listeners there. I don't have an example handy, but here is the source for TraceSource-- http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/Dotnetfx_Vista_SP2/8@0@50727@4016/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/NetFxQFE/ndp/fx/src/CompMod/System/Diagnostics/TraceSource@cs/1/TraceSource@cs

Comment: TraceSources are normally declared as static variables, so they are set up and configured very early in the AppDomain life cycle. I think your code is too late.